# Triangle of Stars using recursion Python

Tags: python, recursion

So I have an assignment to write some simple functions recursively. One of them is to make a triangle of stars based on an inputted height. for example:

stars(5)

will print out:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

and this function works just fine in doing that.

```
def stars(height):
    x = 1
    while x <= height:
        print ('*' * x)
        x += 1
```

How can I write this recursively? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for this:

```
def recurse_triangle(num, char):
    if num > 0:
        recurse_triangle(num-1, char)
        print(char*num)

recurse_triangle(5, '*')
```

Output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this one to print in both ascending and descending form?

```
def stars(n, descending=True):
    if (descending):
        print '*'*n

    if n==1:
        if not descending:
            print '*'
        return

    stars(n-1, descending)
    if not descending:
        print '*'*n

stars(5)
print
stars(5, descending=False)
```

#### Output:

```
*****
****
***
**
*

*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: how would you do this so that you can call it once and have the full output?e.g. <br/>
`stars(5)`
returns
    *****
    ****
    ***
    **
    *
    *
    **
    ***
    ****
    *****

Answer (score 0):

That's easy, just add one until the height is reached. Use a default value and call `star(12)`.

```
def star(h, n = 1):
    if h == n:
        print n * '*'

    if h != n:
        print n * '*'
        star(h, n + 1)
```

Comment: You're printing `n * '*'` regardless of whether `h` is equal or unequal to `n`. You can take it out of the `if` statements and have a single `if` statement that calls `star(h, n+1)` if `h` is unequal to `n`.

Comment: Oh, yes my bad. That's some what obvious but yes you are right. I thought that you were referring to replacing that line with the other not changing the order.

Answer (score 0):

Initially call it with the desired height and 0 for the number of stars.

```
 def stars(height, x):
        if x < height:
           return
        else:
           print ('*' * x)
           stars(height, x + 1)
```

Comment: Yeah, I had that same idea. To use another value to cap the height.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way to call it recursively.

```
def stars(height, sub=0):
    if sub < height:
        print "*"*(height-(height-1)+sub)
        stars(height, sub+1)

stars(5)
```

Results:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```